# Sendgrid Inbound Parse‘s body don't have "html" filed when email's attachment have a txt file

Tags: text, sendgrid, attachment

I am now using sendgrid's inbound parse.
When I send an email with only two pictures and some text, like this.

[image]

I get:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  headers: 'Received: by xxxxxxxxxx.sendgrid.net with SMTP id xxxxxxxxx Mon, 29 Nov 2021 07:03:20 +0000 (UTC)\n' +
    ...
    'From: Weijia Liu <xxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com>\n' +
    'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="Apple-Mail=XXXXXX-3C6125300A4D"\n' +
    'Mime-Version: 1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 15.0 \\(3693.20.0.1.32\\))\n' +
    'Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2021 15:03:15 +0800\n' +
    'Subject: Test Subject\n' +
    'Cc: Weijia Liu <weijialiu@XXXXXX.com>, veejaliu@XXXXXX.com\n' +
    'To: from-XXXXXX <XXXX-XXX-XXXX-1@XXX-XXX.XXXXX.com>\n' +
    'Message-Id: <3E749EC9-XX-XXXXX-9EE3-XXXXX@XXXXX.com>\n' +
    'X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.3693.20.0.1.32)\n',
  dkim: '{@XXXXX.com : pass}',
  'content-ids': '{"A413684D-A1E0-4452-A357-068A0BF9BF8F":"attachment2","101ADBDA-B1F9-4976-A54A-C9F23855B334":"attachment1"}',
  to: 'from-liuweijia <random-XXXX-XXXXX-1@XXXX-XXXXX.XXXXX.com>',
  cc: 'Weijia Liu <weijialiu@XXXXX.com>, veejaliu@XXXXX.com',
  html: '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></head><body style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; line-break: after-white-space;" class=""><div>00000000000<br class="">1111111111111<br class=""><img apple-inline="yes" id="FAF1B797-8349-46FA-B485-52FDFBA87D2E" width="165" height="167" src="cid:101ADBDA-B1F9-4976-A54A-C9F23855B334" class=""><br class="">22222222222<br class=""><img apple-inline="yes" id="8A3199BF-E1D6-45C6-A781-A32421917F4B" width="165" height="167" src="cid:A413684D-A1E0-4452-A357-068A0BF9BF8F" class=""><br class="">333333333333<br class="">444444444444<br class="">555555555555<br class=""><br class="">666666666666<br class="">777777777777</div></body></html>',
  from: 'Weijia Liu <weijialiu@XXXXXX.com>',
  text: '00000000000\r\n' +
    '1111111111111\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '22222222222\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '333333333333\r\n' +
    '444444444444\r\n' +
    '555555555555\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '666666666666\r\n' +
    '777777777777',
  sender_ip: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
  envelope: '{"to":["XXXX-XXX-address-1@XX-XXX.XXXXX.com"],"from":"weijialiu@XXXXXX.com"}',
  attachments: '2',
  subject: 'Test Subject',
  'attachment-info': '{"attachment2":{"filename":"liuyifei.jpg","name":"liuyifei.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","content-id":"A413684D-A1E0-4452-A357-068A0BF9BF8F"},"attachment1":{"filename":"liuyifei.jpg","name":"liuyifei.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","content-id":"101ADBDA-B1F9-4976-A54A-C9F23855B334"}}',
  charsets: '{"to":"UTF-8","cc":"UTF-8","filename":"UTF-8","html":"us-ascii","subject":"UTF-8","from":"UTF-8","text":"us-ascii"}',
  SPF: 'pass'
}
```

As you can see, I get a field named "html". Through it, I can get the format of the whole email.

When the email I receive contains an attachment of type TXT, like this:

[image]

there is no HTML field in the body.

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  ...
  to: 'from-liuweijia <XXXXX-XXXXX-address-1@XXXXX-XXXXX.XXXXX.com>',
  cc: 'Weijia Liu <weijialiu@XXXXX.com>, veejaliu@XXXXX.com',
  from: 'Weijia Liu <weijialiu@XXXXX.com>',
  text: '00000000000\r\n1111111111111\n',
  sender_ip: '209.85.215.182',
  envelope: '{"to":["random-email-address-1@XXXXX-XXXXX.testhtm.com"],"from":"weijialiu@XXXXX.com"}',
  attachments: '6',
  subject: 'Test Subject',
  'attachment-info': '{"attachment2":{"charset":"us-ascii","type":"text/plain"},"attachment6":{"charset":"us-ascii","type":"text/plain"},"attachment3":{"filename":"liuyifei.jpg","name":"liuyifei.jpg","type":"image/jpeg"},"attachment5":{"filename":"EmailTest.txt","name":"EmailTest.txt","type":"text/plain"},"attachment1":{"filename":"liuyifei.jpg","name":"liuyifei.jpg","type":"image/jpeg"},"attachment4":{"charset":"us-ascii","type":"text/plain"}}',
  charsets: '{"to":"UTF-8","cc":"UTF-8","filename":"UTF-8","subject":"UTF-8","from":"UTF-8","text":"us-ascii"}',
  SPF: 'pass'
}
```

Does anyone know why?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The second body you posted is much shorter than the first. They both have `...` at the top indicating, to me at least, that there's more data that is hiding. How are you logging and collecting this data? How are you receiving the incoming email, can you share the code?

Comment: THanks for your advice. I added `...` myself. Because there are too many returned contents, I removed some useless interference information. This is not the main reason.

Comment: You can’t say that one field is missing, then omit other fields. Can you share the full data? And the code you are using to receive it?